# How do I append JSON objects in Logic Apps?

Tags: json, azure, json.net, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

We have an incoming JSON message and would like to add some additional JSON data (JSON object with some fields) to the original message. How can I add the JSON Object "GlossDef" to the position outlined below?

```
{
   "glossary":{
      "title":"example glossary",
      "GlossDiv":{
         "title":"S",
         "GlossList":{
            "GlossEntry":{
               "ID":"SGML",
               "SortAs":"SGML",
               "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
               "Acronym":"SGML",
               "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
***            "GlossDef":{
***              "para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
***               "GlossSeeAlso":[
***                  "GML",
***                  "XML"
***               ]
***            },
               "GlossSee":"markup"
            }**
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the 'addProperty' method in the expressions tab. Here is a question on the powerusers platform regarding this.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-add-a-new-property-to-an-object-type-variable-in-Apply-to/td-p/155685

I validated it in a test example with the following steps:
[image]

Step 1 - This is the initial object where ever you are getting it from. 
Step 2 - This is just initializing a variable with the object to add, you may have to do this in some dynamic fashion but the concept is still the same. 
Step 3 - Parse the object from step one, so we can extract the sub object we want to append to.
Step 4 - Extract the sub object in this case we will choose 'GlossEntry' from the Dynamic Content list coming from the parse json.
Step 5 - Using a compose, use the expression tab and use the 'appProperty' to add 'ObjectToAdd' into 'ChildObject'. Look like this: addProperty(variables('ChildObject'), 'GlossDef', variables('ObjectToAdd'))

That should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you! How do I merge the result of Compose (step 5) back to step 1? I would like to have the full json object.

Comment: You would basically skip step 4 and update step 5 pointing to the object like step 4 is doing. Then you have the whole object still.

Comment: Read how the addProperty work when you start typing and which parameters to pass in. 

`addProperty( '{parentObject}', '{objectNameAsString}', '{childObjectToAdd}')`

So in your case, `addProperty(variables('FullJsonMessage')['GlossEntry'], 'GlossDef', variables('ChildObjectToAdd'))`